# Adjust Vite config to generate separate output files for each CSS style in a Vue3

Tags: css, sass, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to generate a build for Vite/Vue3, and I was wondering if it's possible to adjust the Vite config to generate an output file for each of the style CSS. So, currently `style.css` in the root folder is being overwritten every time I generate a build.

I want the final folder structure to look like this:

```
 dist 
 - Main
    - <type>
      - icons
      - css
        - style.css // I need my style.css here for the specific type
    - <type 2>
      - icons
      - css
        - style.css  // I need my style.css here for the specific type
    ....
 - Library.js
 - Library.umd.js
 - Style.css // If Possible I don't need to generate this here and should be inside it's specific type folder
```

This is my Vite Config

```
const types = [
  "type",
  "type1",
  "type2"
];

const config = {
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        // Styles
        {
          src: "src/assets/styles",
          dest: "",
        },
        // Scripts
        {
          src: "src/scripts",
          dest: "",
        },
        // Assets
        ...types.map((type) => ({
          src: `src/assets/icons/${type}/*.svg`,
          dest: `main/${types}/icons`,
        })),
      ],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: { requireReturnsDefault: true },
    emptyOutDir: true,
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/index.ts"),
      name: "Library",
      fileName: "library",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
        @import "@/assets/styles/<type>/*.scss";
        // Other Additional Import SCSS Here
      `,
      },
    },
  },
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
  },
};
```